# Removing an element from a composite pattern structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

Suppose we have the simplest structure, classes `Component`, `Leaf : Component` and `Composite : Component`. Each object of `Leaf` class has an `int id` which gives it its identity. The composite class would have sth like:

```
class Composite : public Component
{
public:
    void removeComponent(Component*);
// other stuff
private:
    std::vector<Component*> coll;
};
```

And leaf class sth like:

```
class Leaf : public Component
{
public:
    //stuff
    int getID();
private:
    int id;
};
```

And the question is how to define the function `removeComponent(Component* cmp)`. cmp is actually a `Leaf`, but I need to access the `Component` vector coll, so it needs to be a `Component` (I think). The removeComponent method takes a `Leaf` object, and removes all other Leaves with the same ID, from the whole structure.

Now, I have thought of two ways (neither of which works :P):

***First***

```
void Composide::removeComponent(Component* cmp)
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        (*it)->removeComponent(cmp);
    // where removeComponent is defined as virtual in Component, but
    // the problem is that Leaf cannot erase itself from the collection
    }

}
```

***Second***

```
void Composide::removeComponent(Component* cmp)
    {
        std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
        for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
        {
            if((*it)->equals(*cmp))
            it = erase(it);
        // But here I can't define equals function for Composite elements,
    // so then I'd have to make functions which return the type of Component,
    // and in case of Composite call recursively the function and
    // in the case of Leaf call the equals() function and erase if needed.
    // This however looks like really bad OOP practice, and I'd like to avoid
    // using those methods which return type..
        }

    }
```

There has to be a neat, nice way to do this. I kind of think that the method should look something like the upper-mentioned 1st way, only I really don't know how to enable the `Leaf` to delete itself from the vector. Help me please? :)

Comment: Is it mandatory that Leaf inherit from Component?

Comment: Also, even though coll is defined as a vector of Components, shouldnt it be a vector of Leaf objects? Or can it have both Composite and Leaf objects?

Comment: @Brady yeah, because that way the collection of Components consists of both Leaves and Composite elements with their own collections, forming a tree-like structure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be getting confused as to what `Component` is exactly. Is it some business object, or is it a class representing a tree node? If it's a tree node, then all tree nodes should support the same operations to allow easy recursion.

As such I would move the definition of `removeComponent()` to the base `Component` class and make it virtual. You can provide an empty implementation in `Component`.

Your composite implementation is then simply:

```
void Composide::removeComponent(Component* cmp)
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it)->equals(*cmp))
           it = erase(it);
        else
           (*it)->removeComponent(cmp);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Regarding Id's

Again, I think you might be muddling two concepts, Component id's, and Components.
(Perhaps it would be better if you renamed `Component` to `TreeItem`?)

Your current `removeComponent()` function takes a `Component` pointer, thus inferring that any `Component` can be removed from the tree (including `Composites`). This seems correct to me. You might well need to remove `Composites`. Thus, you can simply compare pointers.

However, you then seem to be comparing Id's (via an assumed equality overload) that only `Leafs` have.

If you want to provide an additional function to remove by Id, then I would move the GetID() function to the base `Component` class too, and compare against that. `Composite` objects can return -1 or some other null marker.

eg.

```
void Composite::getID()
{
   return -1;
}

void Composide::removeComponent(Component* cmp)
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it) == cmp)
           it = erase(it);
        else
           (*it)->removeComponent(cmp);
    }
}

void Composite::removeComponentById(int id)
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it)->getID() == id)
           it = erase(it);
        else
           (*it)->removeComponentById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, this is great, just two questions: 

1. Seeing as Composite doesn't have an ID, should I define `equals` for Composite as always returning `false`, so it just jumps to recursion in case of Composite?

2. In the `Leaf::equals(Component *c)` method, the `Component` will always be a `Leaf`, so should I just define a virtual `getID()` method in Component, which will return ID in case of `Leaf` and return anything in case of `Composite`, seeing as `getID()` will never actually be called for `Composite`?

Comment: One thing I am missing is: Who keeps reference of the removedComponents ? Doesnt remove mean, that we as well delete the complete sub-branch? If not, the remove method should at least return a pointer to the removedComponent, in order to have the possibility to store the ref to it elsewhere.

Comment: Do you not have the references held elsewhere? I would return an array from your removeComponent() function if you need them.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for this approach:

```
void Composide::removeComponent(Component* cmp)
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it)->equals(*cmp))
        {
            delete *it;
            coll.erase(it);
            return;//can there be more than one?
        }
        else
        {
            //iterative call
            it->removeComponent(*cmp);
        }
    }
}

void Composide::~Composite()
{
    std::vector<Component*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it)
    {
        delete *it;
        it = coll.erase(it);
    }
}
```

The destructor of Composite should than take care of all sub-components of itself, if a Composite was deleted.

Generally I would recommend usage of smart pointers. Than deleting would not be needed any more.

The equals(..) method should than be pure virtual in the Component and implemented in each child.

Edit: Added if/else for iterative search

Comment: If you delete an object contained in the vector, it's good practice to remove the pointer from the vector as well.

Comment: Uhm, first of  all, delete *it doesn't remove the element from the vector. Secondly, your code completely neglects the possibility of *it being a Composite instead of LEaf :)

Comment: Fixed the delete-stuff ... *it is a component. You should not care here if the real type is a leaf or a composite. This should be the the task of the equals from my POV.